How can I backup my private Keys from Kleopatra
How can I export my private key from Kleopatra to backup it or use it in a new computer etc.

How can I export my private key from Kleopatra?

Open Kleopatra, select your own certificate, click on File ⇾ Export
private certificate.

Select the path and the file name of the output file.

Source: Gpg4win Compendium -- 19 Importing and exporting a private certificate

Can you explain me to generate second private key?
